# Anaconda environment and pycharm

Tags: pycharm, conda

I am having trouble getting pycharm to recognize the python interpreter in an anaconda environment.  I was able to set the project interpreter ([instructions here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html)) as you can see below:

[image: added conda environment interpreter]

However the ide still complains that it cannot find modules that are clearly listed under the interpreter:

[image: ide cannot find nose dependency, yet it is clearly listed (4th) in interpreter packages]

I'm operating in windows and have talked to a few people with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thew new pycharm version appears to fix this problem and is at: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/JetBrains+PyCharm+Preview+%28EAP%29

Thanks to pycharm support for helping me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you set it up correctly. I would try invalidating the caches and restarting.  I've had a similar problem to this before and that did it.

Go to "File" -> "Invalidate Caches/Restart" and choose "Invalidate and Restart".[image]

Comment: unfortunately still no luck.  After invalidation and restart the dependencies are still not found and the interpreter still lists them.

Comment: Do you see "nose" in the "External Libraries" -> "Python" -> "site-packages" section on the left? Perhaps try synchronizing (right click) the "site-packages". You can also try switching out of the environment and back in. Or confirming the package is there in the command line. Odd issue

Comment: actually I don't see anything under extended definitions for the pyChemSim environment (even after synchronize - [pyChemSim env image](http://imgur.com/Rx1PzoE)).  
When I switch to conda's root python interpreter I do see site-packages ([root interpreter image](http://imgur.com/DyBwHfC)), so I could install all my packages to root, but it would be nice to use environments.