# Anaconda, and Pycharm set up. Error on Manjaro KDE

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

So  I have been encountering some problems with setting up a proper Anaconda Interpreter with Pycharm. Per the documentation on [the anaconda website](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/), and [the Pycharm website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html) they are suggesting that I go to the Add Interpreter settings near the bottom right of the Pycharm GUI, once I click on the current interpreter.

For example,Pycharm is saying my current interpreter is Python 3.9 . Then click on the Conda Environment which I did, however, when I have done so I am getting an Error Message like:
`CondaError: Unable to create prefix directory '/opt/anaconda/envs/pythonProject9'.`

Here is the command output as well:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /opt/anaconda/envs/pythonProject9

  added / updated specs:
    - python=3.9


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  _libgcc_mutex      pkgs/main/linux-64::_libgcc_mutex-0.1-main
  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/linux-64::ca-certificates-2021.4.13-h06a4308_1
  certifi            pkgs/main/linux-64::certifi-2020.12.5-py39h06a4308_0
  ld_impl_linux-64   pkgs/main/linux-64::ld_impl_linux-64-2.33.1-h53a641e_7
  libffi             pkgs/main/linux-64::libffi-3.3-he6710b0_2
  libgcc-ng          pkgs/main/linux-64::libgcc-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0
  libstdcxx-ng       pkgs/main/linux-64::libstdcxx-ng-9.1.0-hdf63c60_0
  ncurses            pkgs/main/linux-64::ncurses-6.2-he6710b0_1
  openssl            pkgs/main/linux-64::openssl-1.1.1k-h27cfd23_0
  pip                pkgs/main/linux-64::pip-21.0.1-py39h06a4308_0
  python             pkgs/main/linux-64::python-3.9.4-hdb3f193_0
  readline           pkgs/main/linux-64::readline-8.1-h27cfd23_0
  setuptools         pkgs/main/linux-64::setuptools-52.0.0-py39h06a4308_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/linux-64::sqlite-3.35.4-hdfb4753_0
  tk                 pkgs/main/linux-64::tk-8.6.10-hbc83047_0
  tzdata             pkgs/main/noarch::tzdata-2020f-h52ac0ba_0
  wheel              pkgs/main/noarch::wheel-0.36.2-pyhd3eb1b0_0
  xz                 pkgs/main/linux-64::xz-5.2.5-h7b6447c_0
  zlib               pkgs/main/linux-64::zlib-1.2.11-h7b6447c_3


Preparing transaction: ...working... failed



==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.9.2
  latest version: 4.10.1

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong? Does anyone need pictures for the PATH?  I am not certain if my problem is similar to another individual on here who [asked a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436425/anaconda-environment-and-pycharm). My Pycharm IDE is update for what its worth.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: @bad_coder I do apologize for not reading the guidelines. It should contain text rather than images.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen the question because the error has been included as text.

Answer (score 0):

The error (which you should have copy-pasted, not screenshotted) says

> Unable to create prefix directory `/opt/anaconda/envs/pythonProject9`
>
> Check you have sufficient permissions.

My best guess is that you've installed Anaconda as `root` (e.g. using `sudo`) and are using PyCharm as a regular user (as you should).

If possible, tell PyCharm (or Anaconda) to use a different base path for the environment it's attempting to create, e.g. one under your home directory, or if you're feeling daring, you might chmod `/opt/anaconda/envs` so you, too, can write there.

Comment: Hey @AKX thanks for the response.  I'll try that solution and respond back if it works or not. Really do appreciate it.